# Splitting a dataframe with many labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, subset

I'm trying to split my data by different labels, like this:

```py
dfa = df_a[((df_a['label'] == 0) | (df_a['label'] == 15) | (df_a['label'] == 16))]
```

And this works fine for small amounts of numbers. However, I want to do this for many values.
for example:

```py
to_train = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,17, 18, 19, 20) # this can change
dfb = [i for i in to_train if df_b['label']==i] # ValueError
```

This spits outs an error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I've read the [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) with this error, but I am already using bitwise operators, they don't address many conditions from what I understand.

How do I split the dataframe based on what's in the tuple/list/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
to_train = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,17, 18, 19, 20)
dfb = dfa[df_a['label'].isin(to_train)]
```

Comment: This works, just needed to change to `dfb = df_b[df_b['label'].isin(to_train)]` for my code specifically.